# List Checkbox change event not fire in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

List Checkbox change event not fire in jquery.

List Creation:

```
$("#my_list").append("<li><input type='checkbox' class='my_list_checkbox' value='"+id+"' name='"+name+"'/><img class=\""+icon_class+"\" /><label style='padding-left:25px'>"+name+"</label></li>");
```

**I tried following events,but no one works,how solve this issue?**

```
$(".my_list_checkbox").on("change",function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});

$(".my_list_checkbox").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});

$("#my_list .my_list_checkbox").on("change",function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});

$("#my_list .my_list_checkbox").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});

$("#my_list li").delegate("input[type:checkbox]","change",function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});

$("#my_list > li > input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
$("#my_list").on('change', "input[type=checkbox]",function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

or

```
$("#my_list").on('change', ".my_list_checkbox",function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.my_list_checkbox').change(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

If you wish to go through the parent element, try 
    $('#my_list").find('.my_list_checkbox').change(function(){
        console.log("clicked");
    });

In this scenario you can also try using .focusout() function if .change isn't working your way...

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation, As `#my_list` is parent of `.my_list_checkbox` and when ever element with class `.my_list_checkbox` is added to `#my_list` event is binding automatically.

```
$("#my_list").on("change", ".my_list_checkbox" ,function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#my_list .my_list_checkbox").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

or

```
$("#my_list").on('click', ".my_list_checkbox",function(){
   console.log("clicked");
});
```